# mvc Ajax How to upate serialized model with formCollection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a page, which will send back the serialzed Model to the controller. In this case I'm using ajax.

In the View I have the following code:

```
@Html.Hidden("processViewModel", new Microsoft.Web.Mvc.MvcSerializer().Serialize(Model, SerializationMode.Signed))
```

And the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PreviewSample([Deserialize]ProcessViewModel processViewModel /*FormCollection form*/)
```

and here is my ajax code:

```
function GetPreview() {


var json = $('form').serializeObject();
complete = false;

json['ProcessDTO.FileUploadDTO.TempUploadFileDTO.FileInformation.HasHeader'] = false; // $('input[name="ProcessDTO.FileUploadDTO.TempUploadFileDTO.FileInformation.HasHeader"]').is(':checked');

alert($('input[name="ProcessDTO.FileUploadDTO.TempUploadFileDTO.FileInformation.HasHeader"]').is(':checked'));

var jsonData = JSON.stringify(json);
var url = ROOT + '/request/previewsample/';

if (lastPreviewCall != undefined) {
    if (lastPreviewCall.status != 200) {
        lastPreviewCall.abort();
    }
}

lastPreviewCall = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 //   dataType: 'json',
    data: jsonData,
    otherParam: true,
    async: true,
    success: function (res) {

        $('#preview').find('tbody').find('tr').remove();

        var selected = $('.addressType:checked').attr('data-hideClass');

        for (var i = 0; i < res.PreviewData.length; i++) {
            var entry = '<tr>';

            var row = res.PreviewData[i];

            for (var u = 0; u < row.length; u++) {
                if (u == 0 && selected == 'consumer') {
                    entry += '<td></td>';
                }
                else {
                    entry += '<td><span>' + row[u] + '</span></td>';
                }
            }
            entry += '</tr>';
            $('#preview').find('tbody').append(entry)
        }
    }
});
```

}

So now I have a checkbox, which is default true in this model and when I uncheck it, the ajax will send the serialized model back to the controller, but the checkbox has always the value true.

how can i update the model?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why are you sending a model to the view and posting it all back again unchanged?

Comment: becouse I need the data in the controller, that i don't have to collect it again. And the checkbox changed from true to false...

Comment: Your using MVC. Dont try to mimic web forms `ViewState`. Get the model again in the POST method (just use `$('form').serialize()` to serialize the form controls and no stringify or `contentType`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add

```
  TryUpdateModel(processViewModel);
```

in the controller, and then is everything fine...